# Convert GeoTiff files to netCDF

Tags: geotiff-tiff, netcdf

i am carrying out a research on dust, i have a low programming skills, but in order for me to do this effectively, i need to determine the soil moisture of the study area. But the soil moisture files i have are in GeoTiff format, can anyone suggest how to convert these files from a GeoTiff to NetCDF file.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Answer (score 3):

This can be easily done with GDAL using the code:
    `gdal_translate -of netCDF input.tif output.nc`
Please got through the site once. I am sure someone would have answered this already.

Answer (score 1):

In ArcGIS (which I hope you have available) there is a tool called "Raster to NetCDF" which should be just what you need.[image: screenshot of ArcGIS toolbox]